# How do I exclude files from the type search in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already added my files to the `files.exclude` setting, and they disappeared. But my webpack created a bunde.js which contains all the same symbols as my actual source code and now when I do a type search, the results are full of duplicates and I keep clicking and navigating to the one in bundle.js instead of my real source file that I want to edit.

Answer (score 0):

files.exclude removes files from the file explorer.

search.exclude will remove files from any searches.

I would expect you could make search.exclude mirror your files.exclude setting to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: it says search.exclude inherits from files.exclude, and I did that on top of that anyway - still doesnt work

Comment: I have my webpack dumping to a folder called wwwroot. I have that folder excluded in both search and file explorer and it works for me. Do you mind posting what you have set in your settings related to this?

Comment: @alexriedl What glob patterns are you using? I am having the same issue. I have added patterns to `files.exclude`, `files.watcherExclude`, and `search.exclude`. I still get undesired results when I use **Go to Definition** and **Find All References**.

Comment: My current exclude setting: "files.exclude": {
        ".vs": true,
        "**/bin": true,
        "**/bower_components": true,
        "**/node_modules": true,
        "**/obj": true,
        "**/wwwroot": true,
        "**/.env": true
    },